# What causes this return() to create a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, return, ascii-art

I need this program to create a sheet as a list of strings of ' ' chars and distribute text strings (from a list) into it. I have already coded return statements in python 3 but this one keeps giving

```
return(riplns)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's the return(riplns) on line 39. I want the function to create a number of random numbers (randint) inside a range built around another randint, coming from the function ripimg() that calls this one.

I see clearly where the program declares the list I want this return() to give me. I know its type. I see where I feed variables (of the int type) to it, through .append(). I know from internet research that SyntaxErrors on python's return() functions usually come from mistype but it doesn't seem the case.

```
#loads the asciified image ("/home/userX/Documents/Programmazione/Python projects/imgascii/myascify/ascimg4")
#creates a sheet "foglio1", same number of lines as the asciified image, and distributes text on it on a randomised line

#create the sheet foglio1
def create():
    ref = open("/home/userX/Documents/Programmazione/Python projects/imgascii/myascify/ascimg4")
    charcount = ""
    field = []
    for line in ref:
        for c in line:
            if c != '\n':
                charcount += ' '
            if c == '\n':
                charcount += '*' #<--- YOU GONNA NEED TO MAKE THIS A SPACE IN A FOLLOWING FUNCTION IN THE WRITER.PY PROGRAM
                for i in range(50):#<------- VALUE ADJUSTMENT FROM WRITER.PY GOES HERE(default : 50):
                    charcount += ' '
                charcount += '\n'
        break
    for line in ref:
        field.append(charcount)
    return(field)

#turn text in a list of lines and trasforms the lines in a list of strings 

def poemln():
    txt = open("/home/gcg/Documents/Programmazione/Python projects/imgascii/writer/poem")
    arrays = []
    for line in txt:
        arrays.append(line)
    txt.close()
    return(arrays)

#rander is to be called in ripimg()
def rander(rando, fldepth):
    riplns = [] 
    for i in range(fldepth):
        riplns.append(randint((rando)-1,(rando)+1)
    return(riplns) #<---- THIS RETURN GIVES SyntaxError upon execution

#opens a rip on the side of the image.
def ripimg():
    upmost = randint(160, 168)
    positions = []
    fldepth = 52 #<-----value is manually input as in DISTRIB function.
    positions = rander(upmost,fldepth)
    return(positions)
```

I omitted the rest of the program, I believe these functions are enough to get the idea, please tell me if I need to add more.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around your `return` statements?

Comment: @DroidX86 Those are totally fine.

Comment: @Vicrobot I know. Redundant but not the source of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incomplete set of previous line's parenthesis .

In this line:-

```
riplns.append(randint((rando)-1,(rando)+1)
```

You have to add one more brace at the end. This was causing error because python was reading things continuously and thought return statement to be a part of previous uncompleted line.

Comment: Thank you, how could I not see that? Feeling stupid. Thank you for the flash-rapid help.

I'm accepting the answer as conclusive soon as the site lets me.